# How to print a given list with all the words containing vowels removed (using only List Comprehension)?

Tags: python, pycharm, list-comprehension

Trying to understand List Comprehension better. Suppose I have two lists, one of random words and another containing vowels. How to print a third list (say: "new_list") that only contains the words that don't contain any vowels, using only List Comprehension?.

```py
list1 = ['apples', 'owl', 'signature', 'try', 'hello', 'cry']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

Output:

```
['try', 'cry']
```

Comment: Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint): `[word for word in list1 if set(word).isdisjoint(vowels)]`

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```py
new_list = [x for x in list1 if all(y not in vowels for y in x)]
```

**What it does:**

- Iterates through `list1`
- Checks the letters in `x`
- If none are in `vowels`, it adds `x` to `new_list`

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [word for word in list1 if not any(v in word for v in vowels)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.